# How to work with calls to different apis and formik fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, formik, react-select

I'm working on easy (at first glance) feature.

I'm having 2 APIs:

1. get/users - it's an array with users (objects) with two important properties: userId and city - I can use get/user?userId=X and get/user?city=X - I cannot use both params simultanously
2. get/cities - it's an array with cities (objects) with a lot of props but the one is important is city - I can use get/city?city=X

I want to have 2 fields both react-select/creatable components. Functionalities that should be included:

- after inserting 3 characters in user field I want to make an API call - as a quick search
- user can then select any option he want
- meanwhile according to user's choice there should be 2nd field filled with the proper information - user can belong only to one city
- the same goes for city field - after inserting 3 characters I want to make an API call - as a quick search
- after selecting any value from available options in the city field I want to make an API call to users?city={selectedCity} endpoint and according to this I want to fill options array for the user

Problems that I'm facing:

- too many requests if the user is inputing for example 8 characters (so I have 5 requests) - I've tried to used debounce from lodash and AbortController but the problem is that it's blocking requests that should be sent
- inconsistencies between state and actual options in select
- too long response time if user is 'playing' with input - for example inserting 10 characters, removing 3 and so on - debounce sounds great but I couldn't solve the problem with blocking required requests because in the end there should be made 2 api calls - one to users/ and one to cities/ but using debounce I'm blocking one of them
- after selecting any userId in the first field there is call to cities/ endpoint because value was updated - but this call is unnecessary

Right now I'm trying to do it using:

- react
- typescript
- formik
- react-select/creatable
- lodash

Maybe you have any knowledge about tool that may help me in this task? I thought it'll be easy one but my assumpions were incorrect or I'm overthinking and making it difficult.